# Verifying Xcode 7.1 launcher appears for long time

Tags: launcher, osx-elcapitan, xcode6.4, xcode7.1

I've update Mac OS from `OS X Yosemite 10.10.4` to `OS X El Capitan 10.11.1.`
Earlier I had *Xcode 6.4* and now I have downloaded *Xcode 7.1*. After installing Xcode 7.1 successfully in application I'm getting `Verifying Xcode 7.1... launcher when Xcode7 is opened`. This *appears for long time and doses't seems to progress.*

[image: Screenshot for question]

Why is this so? Any fix for this?

Answer (score 2):

Open `terminal` from application or type terminal in spotlight and enter below commands.

`cd /Applications` - This will move to the applications directory where Xcode is present

`xattr -d com.apple.quarantine Xcode.app` - This will bypass Gatekeeper in OS X and will launch Xcode quickly

**Note:** *If you have changed name of Xcode (say Xcode7-1) then you should enter ... Xcode7-1.app command. Refer screenshot*

[image: Screenshot for command]